# How to perform simultaneous tap gestures in few different locations using Xcode UI Test?

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I would like to perform a tap gesture in different locations at the same time. Is it possible to do it using Xcode UI Test?

Answer (score 0):

**Tapping on a specific location with UI Testing**:

Relevant documentation, thanks as always to Joe Masilotti: http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Classes/XCUICoordinate.html

Note that the CGVector's created from offsets by ratio; if you set in this example xOffset and yOffset to .5, it'll be in the center of the screen.

> let tapCoordinate = app.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(dx:
>   xOffset, dy: yOffset)) 
>   tapCoordinate.tap()

Unfortunately, one does not appear to be able to have an XCUICoordinate have two different, uh, coordinate pairs within it, and since the interaction is through the coordinate rather than through the XCUIApplication itself, I don't know how one would tap on the second location. It may well be impossible.